# "His/her" or just "his"?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns

Should I use *his* or *his/her* in the following sentence?

> The user can determine **his** name.

Comment: That depends: where will this sentence be published?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The user can determine **their** name.

According to an irreversible trend, use the universal *their*, avoiding the exclusive *his* and the clumsy *his/her*.

*The Cambridge Guide to English Usage* says: "*their* avoids gratuitous sexism and gives the statement broadest reference."

Comment: i didn't get you sorry my english is weak, you u said `user->their`, why not `users->their`? and i want just one user

Comment: I think their is more suited with *The users*.

Comment: @user22, I add the explanation you are asking for in the answer. Here there is no matter with plural and singular, but with sexism in language.

Comment: @hjpotter92, no, as I said to user22, you should avoid sexist language.

Comment: @Carlo_R. Yeah, just saw usage of `they` in Oxford. Added another reply to supplement yours. :)

Comment: thank you , but i don't want their, my questions is explicit, i want the user of his/her of just his, +1 to both of you

Comment: user22, I thank you. However, if you don't want to use "their" then use "his/her". "His/her" is not wrong, but only clumsy. In this case, if you can, using "her/his" is better than "his/her".

Comment: @Carlo_R. Alphabetic order?

Comment: @hjpotter, yes.

Comment: _Trial and error_ happens in that order chronologically, which is why it's weird to have it the other way. _His/her_ and _her/his_ don't have that issue. It sounds weird because, culturally, men have mostly been put before women. If you want to avoid worrying about sexism or perceived sexism, use _their_.

Comment: @snailplane That's interesting. Didn't think of that. The first two examples, I could say, may also come from sexism, with the idea that women are more family oriented than men. Even if I'm wrong, I will point out that these word orders didn't randomly spring into being. There had to be a reason initially. Probably too complex a topic for the comments, though...

Comment: @AlbeyAmakiir My guess about the order of "his/her" is that it's easier to say (at least when you pronounce "/" as "or").

Comment: @snailplane Isn't it weird, then, that we say "shoes and socks" when the socks go on first?  That's always bothered me!

Answer (score 3):

Just supplementing @Carlo_R.'s reply:

The following is from [**New Oxford American Dictionary**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/they)

> The word they (with its counterparts them, their, and themselves) as a
>   singular pronoun to refer to a person of unspecified sex has been used
>   since at least the 16th century. In the late 20th century, as the
>   traditional use of he to refer to a person of either sex came under
>   scrutiny on the grounds of sexism, this use of they has become more
>   common.

The use of they instead of **"he or she"** is common in *spoken English* and increasingly so in *written English*, although still deplored by some people.

Comment: and now what is the right use ?

Comment: @user2208349 *their* name is perfect. It is becoming common in any case.

Comment: thank you , but i don't want their, my questions is explicit, i want the user of his/her of just his, +1 to both of you

Comment: @user2208349 Then you might want to also provide where you are going to use it. What kind of audience are you expecting to address etc.

Comment: i don't have any audience, i just have this question and i don't know the answer :), i really want to know if the native speakers use his/her or just his, i am sure there is an answer for that. right?

Comment: @user2208349, native speakers mostly use "their".

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing *his name* refers to a user name (on a computer system), right? Anyway you can turn the statement around (passive construction):

> The (*user*) name can be determined/specified by the user.

That avoids using possessive pronouns.

Answer (score 1):

*He* was once acceptable when you wanted to speak of a person whose sex was not known, or stated. Now, it is considered old-fashioned, and other alternatives have been used.

- *He/she*
  Use *he/she* every time you are referring to a person for which the sex is not relevant.
- singular *their*
  Use a sentence like the following: "The user can determine their name."
- Use the plural instead of the singular
  In your case, it would mean to use a sentence like the following: "The users can determine their names."

Somebody still consider the singular *their* not acceptable, and they rather prefer using the plural, as in the last example.

The *Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary* has the following notes about this topic:

> *He* used to be considered to cover both men and women: "Everyone needs to feel he is loved." This is not now acceptable. Instead, after *everybody*, *everyone*, *anybody*, *anyone*, *somebody*, *someone*, etc. one of the plural pronouns *they*, *them*, and *their* is often used:
>
> - Does everybody know what they want?
> - Somebody's left their coat here.
> - I hope nobody's forgotten to bring their passport with them.
>
> Some people prefer to use *he or she*, *his or her*, or *him or her* in speech and writing: "Everyone knows what's best for him or herself." *He/she* or *(s)he* can also be used in writing: "If in doubt, ask your doctor. He/she can give you more information." (You may find that some writers just use *she*.) These uses can seem awkward when they are used a lot. It is better to try to change the sentence, using a plural noun. Instead of saying "A baby cries when he or she is tired" you can say "Babies cry when they are tired."

Answer (score 1):

"His/her" is not grammatically correct. It is a shorthand which used in a kind of abbreviated dialect of English that is found in instruction manuals and such. A conjunction is required: his *or* her.

> The user can determine *his or her* name.

Traditionally, male examples are used in English. The example person is a "he" and that is that. In English, the human race is traditionally called "mankind", a person fallen off a ship is "man overboard", tending to your job is "manning your post" and so on.

However, that kind of speaking and writing tends to make women feel excluded. So this is why we use *he or she* for some unspecified person, or *they*.

But here is another strategy you can use in writing. Simply use masculine pronouns in some examples, and feminine ones in others. In some sections of the document, make the user female and use *she* and *her* (consistently: do not change the user from being a *he* in one sentence to a *she* in a related sentence):

> The user can determine *her* name.

Then in some other sections, make the user *he*.  This way you can avoid creating a sense that women are included, while avoiding repetitions of *his or her*, and without resorting to *they* and *their*. Moreover, compared to using *they*, you create a more active sense that women are included.

Although using plural third person pronouns like *they* and *their* to refer to a single person is widespread and acceptable, it does not sound quite as good as using as singular pronoun for one person. At least, subjectively speaking, not to everyone.

Comment: All I see is a slash, so a valid reading is "his slash her".

Comment: But then, hey, `CU@SKL` is evidently pronounced *see you at school*, right? That doesn't mean we should use "IM speak" outside of IM. A slash instead of "or" when you have the time and space to write "or" just looks lazy and dumb.